# Why does std::vector require move-constructors for its elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, move-semantics

C++98 stated that std::vector elements should have copy-constructors. In C++11 that's no longer the case. Instead, the elements must have move-constructors.

Depending on what you do with std::vector, you may or may not really need to call the copy- or move-constructor, yet only one of them is always formally required by the standard. Why?

**Update:** Apparently, the premise is incorrect. My confusion stemmed from reading answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12251704/3).

Comment: No, the value type of `std::vector` does not need to have a move constructor. Certain member functions however require either that copy- or move construction (potentially via the allocator) or copy assignment or move assignment is valid. Where did you get that information from?

Comment: @dyp, indeed, you can have e.g. vectors of `unique_ptr`. But for sure there is no requirement of mandatory moveable types.

Comment: @vsoftco Not only that, you can even have a `std::vector<std::mutex>`, but it is pretty much immutable. `vector<mutex>(size_t{10})` for example only requires `DefaultInsertable`.

Comment: @dyp nice, that's indeed an extreme, didn't know about it.

Comment: @dyp that should be an answer

Comment: @dyp *Where did you get that information from?* SO :-)

Comment: @MaxB Thanks for the link, Howard Hinnant now has changed that answer and pointed out the requirements only apply to `resize`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As implied in the comments, there isn't simply one blanket set of requirements on all objects you store in a vector. Rather, the requirements are placed on specific operations.

Although a number of operations *do* require than the object type be `MoveConstructible` and/or `MoveAssignable`, copy construction and copy assignment qualify for meeting that requirement--that is, copy constructible is basically a superset of move constructible and (likewise copy assignment vs. move assignment).

The reverse is not true though. For example, if you use the two argument constructor for a vector:

```
std::vector<T> vec(n, t);
```

...then `T` must be copy constructible (because it's going to attempt to create `n` copies of `t` in the vector, and with move construction, it would only be able to create *one* item).

If you wanted to look at it as an inheritance hierarchy, you could think of copy(assignment|construction) as a derived class, and move(assignment|construction) as the base class, so you can implicitly substitute copying for moving but not vice versa.

There are quite a few cases where requirements on elements of a `list` are looser than those on elements of a `vector` or `deque` (requirements on elements of `vector` and `deque` are nearly always identical, the sole exceptions of which I'm aware (thanks @yakk) being `emplace_back`, which requires MoveConstructible for vector, EmplaceConstructible otherwise and the next item listed below--but note its caveat).

If you use `std::vector<x> myvector(i, j);` or `myvector.assign(i, j);`, (where `i` and `j` are iterators) then the requirements on T depend on the class of the iterators--if they're forward iterators, then T only needs to be EmplaceConstructible, otherwise T must be MoveConstructible. Caveat: although this does reflect the current wording in the standard, according to [LWG 2266](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2266) the restrictions for the constructor are incorrect: they should apply regardless of the iterator category, and apply equally to vector and deque. Some future version of the standard will reflect that, but in real use that's how things already are.

In case anybody cares about why that is, and why the special treatment for non-forward iterators: the problem is that with something like an `std::istream_iterator`, there's no way to know ahead of time how many items an iterator range might refer to. With something like random-access iterators, it can simply use `j - i` to determine the number of items, make that much space, and insert appropriately. To work efficiently with `istream_iterator`s, they normally copy the data to the end of the current collection, then after the entire range has been copied/moved into the collection, use `rotate` to move them to the desired location. The extra requirement(s) support using `rotate`.

There's one variant of `insert` that requires elements to be swappable in addition to (Move|Copy)(Constructible|Assignable) if you're doing the insert into a `vector` or `deque` (the reasoning here is similar to that given above: for this variant of `insert`, elements are actually inserted in one place, and then moved around to get them to where they belong).

Comment: "operations that require that T be move constructible also require that it be move assignable" Not true. `push_back`, for instance, doesn't require assignment.

Comment: `deque::emplace_back` shouldn't require copy/move (if it does, the standard errs): `vector::emplace_back` must.

Comment: One of the `insert` overloads also has different requirements.

Comment: @dyp: At least as of N3797, the only variant of `insert` I see citing anything special about vector is the last item cited above, where it depends on the class of the iterators.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oops, this is subject to http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2266

Comment: `assign(i,j)` is not subject to LWG 2266 as far as I can see. (I should stop trying to come up with rationales today. Let's just say there is a specific requirement for `vector` in C++14 IS' `assign(i,j)`.)

Comment: Oh well, it seems `deque::assign` is broken anyway. libc++ uses `push_back` instead of `emplace_back` and therefore requires implicit convertibility (unnecessarily!), and libstdc++ seems to use proxy types for assignment that also require implicit convertibility. libc++'s `deque::assign` should also work fine without MoveConstructible when using `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 1):

Where is it that it states that elements must have move-constructors for std::vector in C++11?  A rule like that would break a lot of existing code since existing classes wouldn't necessarily have move constructors.  It is probably true that you would need either copy-constructors or if you don't have a copy constructor, then you would be required to at least have a move constructor.

Comment: *It is probably true that you would need either copy-constructors or if you don't have a copy constructor, then you would be required to at least have a move constructor* That's what I also thought, however it's not true. As @dyp mentioned in the comments, you can have a vector of elements that have neither copy constructors nor move constructors.

Comment: @vsoftco That's very interesting, but I'm not sure how that would work.  How can a vector resize if it cannot either copy nor move the existing elements?

Comment: I guess that it's immutable. Once you constructed it via the second constructor [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), you're stuck with it, cannot push_back or resize anymore.